# What is the correct value or status code to indicate that a username record could not be updated?

Tags: api, http, rest

I'm implementing a basic service to add usernames to user records in a database.  The service first checks if the username exists and if it does returns some value to tell the client that the username is already taken.  If the username is available it updates the user record and returns "OK".  In this application the client is a native IOS mobile app and the server is node.js.  But that shouldn't be relevant to this question.

For this service, what would you recommend I use as my return values? For example, when successful should I return a status code 200? A boolean value? A custom string? Similarly for the unsuccessful condition what would the recommended and customary return value be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status 201 is intented to be used when some resource is created. So when your user is created you should set status code 201 and set it to 200 when the same request does an update. Additionally you can return the ID id the created/updated user. IMHO you should keep create and update as separate services.

You can use apporpriate 4xx errors (Refer [link](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)) when errors happen. Always keep a status message attribute in your response if your response is XML or JSON. You can set appropriate messages into this and the mobile app can check this message based on the HTTP Status Code you give.

Answer (score 0):

I would return a 201 for the successful condition and a 400 or 409 for the unsuccessful condition.

Hope that helps!

Brandon